# updatepanel doesnt update correctly, must click twice to update

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using an update panel and when I click a button it will update all the panels.

`updapanel1.update()` is very simple, but my data is not updating unless I hit the button twice.

My gridviews shows data for a selected user, and then all the grids reflect that users data.
works fine all the update panels work for the gridviews.

Now for somereason when i try to do a row count and update the panel with the summary, it does not work, i get either the previous users summary or if i hit update again for the same user i get the correct data.

```
'the grids are in these panels
     UpdatePanel1.Update()
            UpdatePanel2.Update()
            UpdatePanel4.Update()
            UpdatePanel6.Update()
            UpdatePanel7.Update()

'the things that are not updateing correctly
            rqnum.Text = GridView3.Rows.Count
            oknum.Text = GridView4.Rows.Count
            xlnum.Text = GridView5.Rows.Count
            dynum.Text = DataList1.Items.Count

            UpdatePanel8.Update()
            Panel1.Visible = False
```

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the code for this we cannot guarantee that we are giving you the right answer, but just a thought.  If the code you posted is the actual code, I would re-order things a bit.

1. Do the updates to the content
2. Then call "update" on the panels

This ensures that your content updates are actually sent to the panels.  My guess is this is why it takes that second click. So something like this.

```
'Update content and toggle visibility of controls
rqnum.Text = GridView3.Rows.Count
oknum.Text = GridView4.Rows.Count
xlnum.Text = GridView5.Rows.Count
dynum.Text = DataList1.Items.Count
Panel1.Visible = False

'Now update all needed panels
UpdatePanel1.Update()
UpdatePanel2.Update()
UpdatePanel4.Update()
UpdatePanel6.Update()
UpdatePanel7.Update()    
UpdatePanel8.Update()
```

Comment: heres the thing, i am updateing my gridviews, and then i want to update the panel with labels that have the counts of all my row count gridviews (seperate for each grid)

Comment: Yes, but if the labels are in the panel, update the text, THEN call the update panel update.  See my just added sample.

Comment: i cant do it that way because my grids need to be updated before my text, how can i do a row count if the data hasnt been updated yet?

Comment: Calling "Update" on the panel will have no impact on the gridview at all.  It simply tells ASP.NET that it must send the content back to the browser that things have updated.

Comment: interesting but either way, still having the problem, the worst part is in debug when i stop the program before the update it has the correct row counts as the text, but it never actually shows them on the page